# Error: EACCES when creating new Ember project

Tags: linux, node.js, ember.js, linux-mint

I just installed Linux Mint (version 17.2) and I'm trying to install Ember. Everything seemed to go fine, but I'm getting this error when I run `ember new testProject`.

```
  create vendor/.gitkeep
EACCES, mkdir '/home/mkm/.npm/mkdirp/0.4.2'
Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/mkm/.npm/mkdirp/0.4.2'
    at Error (native)
```

Per a recommendation in the [Ember Documentation](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/getting-started/) I used [this guide](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) to install Node.js and NPM. Some of what I've read suggest the issue is nodejs was installed with sudo, but apt-get failed when I didn't use sudo.

I attempted to run the new project anyway. `bower install` completed successfully. But `ember serve` failed with `Cannot find module 'chalk'`.

--Version Info

```
$ ember --version
version: 1.13.8
Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
node: 0.12.7
npm: 2.13.4
os: linux x64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only command that was needed to run with sudo for me was:

```
npm install
```

I suggest you delete `node_modules/` in your project directory completely, then run:

```
sudo npm install
```

You can also add option `--verbose` to see if everything is correctly installing and installation isn't stuck.

You could also change permissions for `.npm` directory to avoid some problems like that in future:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /home/mkm/.npm
```

Comment: All that was needed was the sudo npm install. Everything worked great after that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use following commands to install and use npm without sudo:

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.25.4/install.sh | NVM_DIR="/home/your-user-name/.nvm" bash
export NVM_DIR="/home/your-user-name/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"

nvm install 0.12
nvm alias default 0.12

npm install -g ember-cli
npm install -g bower
npm install -g phantomjs
```

Here is a link to nvm repository with latest version and documentation: https://github.com/creationix/nvm